# Only one pipeline of a set of multiple pipelines should run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I try to configure different pipelines in jenkins 2. My Problem ist that all my pipelines need the same workspace path (configugerd with `customWorkspace` in my configuration script).

Now I have to prevent that more than one pipeline is running.

My search always leads me back to the same pages, which unfortunately do not help me :-(

Has anyone already solved the same problem and can give me a hint?

Thank you very much

Comment: i'm not sure this can work.  Check `.lock` file exist in that workspace, if not exist, create this file and execute the pipeline, otherwise skip executing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def locked = false;

pipeline {

    agent any 

    stages {

        stage('check workspace lock status') {
            steps {
                script {
                    locked = fileExists file: '.lock'

                    if(locked == false) {
                        touch file: '.lock'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('build') {
            when {
                beforeAgent true
                expression { locked == false }
            }
            steps {
                // do something you want
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            sh 'rm -f .lock'
        }
    }
}
```